# Is there a feature to put default names in tuples for better code completion and suggestions?

Tags: struct, rust, tuples

Is there a feature to put default names in tuples for better code completion and suggestions? The names would not be obligatory, just a hint.

Something like:

```
struct Rect(width: i32, height: i32);

let r: Rect = (1, 2);
let (a, b) = r; // names while destructuring can be anything
```

Comment: No. Use named fields instead `Rect { width: i32, height: i32 }`

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to define a struct ([The book Chapter 5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html)).

1. Declaring an empty (zero-sized) struct

   ```
   struct Foo;
   ```
2. Declaring a tuple struct

   ```
   struct Bar(i32, u32, String);
   ```
3. Declaring a struct with named fields

   ```
   struct Baz {
       first: i32,
       second: u32,
       third: String,
   }
   ```

There is no other way.

Destructuring works for all three variants.

```
let a = Foo;
let Bar(f, s, t) = Bar(3, 5, String::from("Hallo"));
let Baz { first, second, third } = Baz { first: 3, second: 5, third: String::from("Hello") };
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dce66d2c86990ca457aee4c62287ad27))

Comment: Yeah, I know.
I think it would be nice to have hints in tuples.
For instance given: struct RGB(red: i32,blue: i32, green: i32) .
One could get names hints while writing let rgb = RGB(1, 2, 3) .
C# has feature called semantic names in tuples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: What is the advantage over named fields?

Comment: Less syntactic overhead. It turns out there is already proposal for this https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2584

Comment: I don't think that RFC#2584 does what you want.

Comment: Good point, I will double check this. Advantage over named fields is that you have unnamed fields. Same way as you compare tuple vs. struct.
Basically you have the following: 1. tuple: no names, structural compatibility, (tuples today) 2: tuple with names and structural compatibility (not possible). 3. named fields with structural compatibility 4. named fields without structural compatibility (named fields today)

Comment: @NN_ I'd argue that such a feature would be worse because then you would have **two** names for the same field.

Comment: You already can use several names for the the same tuple item. It is not different in that way.

Comment: @NN_ there's a large difference between the name you give to the **value** that you get out of a tuple (`let (whatever, something) = tup;`) and the name of the **fields** in the tuple (`tup.0`). With your proposed code, you could write `&mut tup.0` and `&mut tup.width` and these two different names would be mutable aliases for the same field, something that is expressly disallowed by Rust.

Comment: tup.0 and tup.width should mean exactly the same thing for the given tuple. Compiler just replaces width with 0.